# CSS input :checked hack

Tags: html, css, sass

in the below code is this possible to change the `color` of deep linking `div` through `input` `checkbox` hack

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  .checkclick:checked .hello {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>

<body>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="checkclick" />
  <span>Hello One next</span>
</div>
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="hello">hello world</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does it work for you? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Maybe `.checkclick:checked + .one .hello` but I'm not sure if that is what you mean

Comment: @AlonEitan if there is code like this
 ```<body>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="checkclick" />
      <span>Hello One next</span>
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <div class="hello">hello world</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>```

Comment: @Kapil with the structure in your comment it is not possible in pure CSS (JS can do it though), you would have to remove the `div` wrapping your checkbox. Though you can use labels with `for="ckeckbox-name"` to trigger your checkbox and place the checkbox anywhere on the site.

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` and `<input>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Comment: @AlonEitan can you help me with javascript how it will work

Comment: What is an "input checkbox hack"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is, you can either use the [element+element selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) or the [sibling selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_previous_siblings.asp).

Example with the the element+element Selector `.checkclick:checked + .one .hello`, try it out:

```css
.checkclick:checked+.one .hello {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="checkclick" />
  <div class="one">
    <div class="two">
      <div class="hello">hello world</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .one .two  .hello {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="checkclick" />
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <div class="hello">hello world</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to change the structure and answer TS comment

> can you help me with javascript how it will work

**Javascript version**

```js
document.getElementById("check").onchange = function() {
  const element = document.getElementById("hello_id");
  element.classList.toggle("blue");
}
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="checkclick" />
    <span>Hello One next</span>
  </div>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="two">
      <div class="hello" id="hello_id">hello world</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JQuery version**

```js
$("#check").change(function() {
  $("#hello_id").toggleClass("blue");
});
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="checkclick" />
    <span>Hello One next</span>
  </div>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="two">
      <div class="hello" id="hello_id">hello world</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```